# Re-generate random choices python

Tags: python, random

I am just wondering if I can make python regenerate random choices it makes?

```
computer player = player 1
user player= player 0

player 0 has [2,3,4,5,6,8,8]
player 1 has [2,1,1,2,2,0,0]
```

player 1 has to generate random choices to choose the number it wants from player 0.
The number can only be the numbers it already has in the list.

If say player 1 chooses 2, it wins because it has Four 2s.

So,
 player 1 can only ask from player 0 number 2 1 or 0.

How can I code in a way that player 1 would choose number 2 instead of 1 or 0 since there is greater chance of winning it chooses number 2? Any idea?

Comment: Whatever code you ran to generate the random choices… run the same code, with the same inputs, and it will re-generate the random choices. Without any more specific details, it's very hard to say anything more specific.

Comment: Uh.  You are making some assumptions that we understand whatever game you're talking about.

Comment: can you make your question clearer? do you want a higher chance of getting the number 2 ot it needs to choose 2. I mean it is easy to choose 2 because you know it exists more. Describe the game in more detail please

Comment: Is this about making player 1 more likely to choose 2 than the other choices? I don't see what this has to do with regenerating random choices, whatever you mean by "re-generate".

Answer (score 1):

It's a little tricky understanding the question, but I take it to mean that you'd like to replay a "random" sequence of numbers.  I'm getting this entirely from the first line of the question, as I don't understand the game as you've written it.

You can do this with `random.seed()`.  For example:

Setting the seed and computing a list of random integers:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.seed(0)
>>> [random.randint(1,100) for i in range(10)]
[85, 76, 43, 26, 52, 41, 79, 31, 48, 59]
```

If you don't reset the seed, doing this again yields:

```
>>> [random.randint(1,100) for i in range(10)]
[91, 51, 29, 76, 62, 26, 91, 99, 82, 91]
```

Resetting the seed, you get the same random number you got the first time:

```
>>> random.seed(0)
>>> [random.randint(1,100) for i in range(10)]
[85, 76, 43, 26, 52, 41, 79, 31, 48, 59]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly this is the scenario:

```
player_1 = gen_random(7)
>>> player_2 = gen_random(7)
>>> player_1
[2, 3, 0, 9, 8, 9, 5]
>>> player_2
[0, 6, 0, 6, 5, 3, 6]
>>> player_choose(player_1)
9
>>> player_choose(player_2)
6
```

each player chooses 7 random numbers from 0 to 9. Then each player chooses from his own 7 chosen numbers.

Here is the code:

```
import random
def gen_random(number):
    rList = []
    for i in range(number):
        rList.append(random.randint(0,9))
    return rList

def player_choose(rList):
    maxIndex = len(rList)-1
    return rList[random.randint(0,maxIndex)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the only clear part of the question so I will answer it:

How can I code in a way that player 1 would choose number 2 instead of 1 or 0 since there is greater chance of winning it chooses number 2? Any idea?

```
>>> p1 = [2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0]
>>> max({n: p1.count(n) for n in set(p1)}.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
2
```

The one liner above will return whatever number there is the most of, 2's in the case.

It works as follows:

```
>>> {n: p1.count(n) for n in set(p1)}
{0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 3}   #creates a dictionary where key: value is number: count
>>> {n: p1.count(n) for n in set(p1)}.items()
[(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 3)]  #shows the items as tuples of (number, count)
```

The rest is just using `max` to find the tuple were the count is highest and then slice result to give the number.